# Is there a document with a list of conjectures or research problems regarding reinforcement learning (like the Millennium Prize Problems)?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, deep-rl, research

Is there a document with a list of conjectures or research problems regarding reinforcement learning like the [Millennium Prize Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really an exhaustive list, but Hutter maintains a small list of problems (click on the bullet point "Universal AI Book" [here](http://www.hutter1.net/)) related to [AIXI](https://jan.leike.name/AIXI.html) (a reinforcement learning agent), some of which have already been solved. The money awards are in the range of 50-500 euros, so they are not as financially important as the [Millennium Prize Problems](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems).